# Integrating an Orchard module that depends on NHibernate 3.x

Tags: nhibernate, orchardcms

We have an existing site that we would like to convert to an Orchard module. The module will need to continue to use it's own database and data access.

Is it possible to use a different version of NHibernate (3.2) to that of the Orchard Framework and what extension points can be used to hook into Begin/End requests so that `ISession`s can be managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, that is not possible. Or at least very very very difficult. Probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was beginning to think just that. I'd got the NH3 assembly referenced but session and transaction management were proving difficult. Fighting against the framework that much suggests you're doing it wrong.